# Bluej not running in Ubuntu machine

Tags: java, linux, bluej

I recently installed bluej from ducke university's website which was written to to teach java programming in coursera courses.
It successfully installed but when i tried to run it was repeatedly giving error and I searched in internet but there were no exact solution given. The error it given was included in this question.
[image]

I even included the code snippet of bluej as well directories inside jvm.

```
unset JAVAPATH
FOUND="false"
for VMNAME in java-8-oracle jdk-8-oracle java-8-openjdk ; do
  for JDKCANDIDATE in /usr/lib/jvm/"$VMNAME"* ; do
```

The directories inside jvm :

[image]

I am complete new to java so please help me to run successfully bluj.

Comment: Please do not post code and other text info as images or links to images - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading blueJ from the official website and reinstalling only one java JDK.
It might be a problem as u have 2 different versions of Java installed and running on one system

Moreover, if you have bluej the try running it in the blueJ application itself it is much easier

Comment: Bluej from official website is working fine but I am interested in downloading it from the version present in duke university website for coursera classes.

Comment: Try reinstalling BlueJ and installing ONLY one version of Java

Answer (score 0):

Even though Duke/Coursera say that you need the 4.11/Older Specific version of BlueJ, it's not actually right. You can install the latest version of BlueJ and use the packages provided by Duke University to run it exactly as they show you.

I was struggling with the same and made a video about it right now.
[How to run BlueJ Duke/Coursera Specific Version 4.11 on Ubutnu or Linux with latest BlueJ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFresR8uEMs)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33143395)

Comment: That was the essential part of the answer. If you just do what the first paragraph says, you don't even have to watch the video.